# Best as a noun in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, noun

Best can be a noun in English like "I did my best" I've seen some translations as "operam navare" "sedulo facere/ago" but there's no "best". This can work for that, but there are other uses "I wish you the best" "Show your best" etc.
Can I use the neutral "optimum" for that or it wouldn't sound correct?